# Shouldn't "toHaveBeenNthCalledWith" test only one instance of the mocked function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

From my understanding, toHaveBeenNthCalledWith within a jest test should test only the "Nth" call with "N" being a non-zero number. My test below returns the Nth call and the one after it. In the test, I give N a value of one and it is showing two. Now I can replaced the one with a two and then it will show 2 and 3. This is causing my test to fail. Are there any suggestions to why it is behaving like this??

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably your mock is saving state between tests, this means that it "holds" previous calls, therefore, you see 4 calls.

Try to use new mock for each test, usually done by configuring the mock in a `beforeEach` hook.

## Edit

You can use [`.toHaveBeenNthCalledWith`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeennthcalledwithnthcall-arg1-arg2-) which specifies which call is under test.

Comment: I do configure the executeQuerySpy beforeEach test. It is making those calls in the same test suite. There are a total of 8 possible calls and I only want to test the first one in this test. I will make additional test to check the other calls.

Comment: Check my addition

Comment: I'm not following you. I am using .toHaveBeenNthCalledWith. Look at the first image again.  I even just modified that test suite to look at each instance of the function that looks at the different types of addresses that I am trying verify. I still get the same results.  Each call is looking at the "specified Nth call" and the one after it.

Comment: I see what the problem is now but I don't know how to fix it. Look at the last image in the question. The expected doesn't match the received, which is clear because it failed. But the received is actually the way it supposed to look. The function that is being mocked takes in two params. One for the sql query and an array of params for the sql query.  The question is HOW do I modify my "Expected" to look like my "Received". I thought I was doing that by feeding the "expectedBenefitQueryParams" to the mock. Obviously not.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I didn't got the question then.
Can you describe what is the issue with the images? from what I see there is difference in spacing of the query, this means that something in the mock is wrong. Can you the mock code?

Comment: I added the actually query that is being fed into the mock function. It is the last image. The second image shows the mock code. The Received in the fourth image is what the Expected should look like. It shows the Query and it shows the params for the query. The purpose of the test is to verify that the params for the sql query are what they supposed to be. In particular, the addr_tp_cd is a specified number and ecrs_id is a specified number.

Answer (score 0):

My overall problem was whitespace. Plus I had to change the way the underlining executeQuery function was being called in the actual controller. So the expect statements in the third image are actually correct. I copied the sql statement from the controller and pasted in the test. I did NOT add tabs and it worked.